# Unable to delete or save new smb.conf

Tags: samba

I am brand new to linux and all related stuffs, so please be gentle. I am trying to get familiar with the sharing process in linux using samba. i have gone through and created the global settings i need and the path and all that but no it wil not let me save it. i hope that is enough info to get started i'm not new to computers just new to linux thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In order to edit system files, you have to open them with admin privileges, for example:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/samba/smb.conf
```

For more info, check out the [RootSudo wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo)